# How can I install craftsman-style door casing where it interferes with hinges?

Tags: trim, door-frame, finishing

I'm planning on updating the casing (ranch style currently) on several door frames in my house to a craftsman style and I'm not sure how the trim will fit near the hinges.

Right now the reveal (R in the picture) between the edge of the and the casing is just about 1/4", maybe 1/16" - 1/32" under. The edges of the hinges are just about even with casing, sometimes overlapping by ~1/32". The center of the hinge pin comes out from the outer face of the jamb 9/16" (D in the picture).

If I put the craftsman trim up with the same 1/4" reveal it will be very close to the hinges, just about touching really. If I use 9/16" thick trim it should have a little clearance from the hinges because of the radius on the trim. But I think I may use something a little thicker than 9/16" so it comes out from the baseboard trim a little on the bottom, in which case the door casing would be right up next to the hinge.

Is there a typical way to work this out? The only way I really see is to have a larger reveal.
[image]

Comment: Depending on the details of the new trim shape, cutting some space around the hinges is not unheard of. Do it neatly if you want it to look good, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that you adjust the reveal to accommodate your hinges. Whether you do this just on the hinge side or all the way around is up to you. It looks like you'll want to paint the jambs before installing the casing anyway, so it shouldn't be an aesthetic problem. Sand down the paint ridge a bit so it doesn't show.

It shouldn't take more than an extra 1/16" to clear the hinges, and even if the casing is against the hinge you're unlikely to have problems.

I absolutely would not carve out for the hinges. This looks amateurish and sloppy, in my opinion, as though you failed to plan well.

Of course, you could always replace your hinges--modern ones tend to have smaller barrels, but I think that's unnecessary. It's also often more hassle than it sounds since screw patterns and leaf size are not standardized.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not adding dimensions because they will vary depending on the trim you choose, but here is a picture of such a hinge in my 1929 Craftsman house.  The trim is generally flat 1x3 or 1x4 with "L" shaped trim to cover the raw edges.

Personally, I'd go with stained wood, but this trim was painted in the late 60's or 70's and would be almost impossible to restore to the original laquer finish without damaging it.
[image]

Comment: Could you add the dimensions of your trim so the OP can see how that matches up with his? Otherwise, this is just the "show" part of "show and tell". ;)